# Characterizing connected sets of $\mathbb R^n$ is terms of differentiable maps for which zero derivative everywhere implies constant

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, connectedness

Let $U $ be an open subset of $ \mathbb R^n$ ; then how to prove that $U$ is connected iff for every differentiable

function $f:U \to \mathbb R$ , $\nabla f(x)=0 \implies f $ is constant on $U$ ?

Comment: Can you prove that any connected open set is path-connected?

Comment: @MiloBrandt : yes , that I can , actually I'm having more trouble with the converse part that is the condition on maps implies connected ..

Comment: @ShaunDev Ah. It might be easier to think of the converse in terms of the following equivalent statement: "Any disconnected space has a non-constant $f$ with zero gradient."

Comment: Suppose $U = (0,1) \cup (2,3)$ in $\mathbb R ^1.$ Can you find a non constant $f$ on $U$ such that $f'\equiv 0?$

Comment: @MiloBrandt , zhw : yes , that I can do if $n=1$ , but I'm having trouble for higher dimensions , please help

Comment: I $U\subset \mathbb R ^n$ is open and not connected, then $U$ is the disjoint union of two nonempty open sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $U$ is open and disconnected.  Then, we can write $U = U_1 \cup U_2$ where each $U_i$ is open and non-empty, and $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$.

Define your function by
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 & x \in U_1\\
0 & x \notin U_1
\end{cases}
$$
Why is this function differentiable?